# How to loop the List records into table using MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored Procedure where I'm loading Comma separated values into Table.

```
CREATE definer = 'root' PROCEDURE List_values_to_table(_list varchar(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE _next TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextlen INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _value INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE ListName VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL;
   iterator:
 LOOP
IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(_list))=0 OR _list is NULL THEN
Leave iterator;
END IF;
SET _next = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_list,',',1);
SET _nextlen = CHAR_LENGHT(_next);
SET _value = TRIM(_next);
SET ListName = _value
SET _list  = INSERT(_list,1,_nextlen+1,'');
END LOOP;
END
```

`CALL List_values_to_table (Test,Test1,Test2)`

Output  :

```
Col  
Test 
Test1 
Test2
```

I'm looking for a  Loop where I can send multiple  list

`CALL List_values_to_table (Test,Test1,Test2),(Emp,Emp1,Emp2)`

I'm looking for output like this.

```
Col  Col1  Col2
Test Test1 Test2
Emp  Emp1  Emp2
```

Comment: you would need to split both lists and loop over the maxnumber to get the dimensions, the question is why want you to do it in mysql.

Comment: @nbk I'm working on MYSQL 5.7 Community edition Work Bench only. Why are you saying dimensions  I need a  Loop where  split the comma  separated values into Rows as displayed above

Comment: the version doesn't matter, it is for all the same. your resultset  has dimension  as it contains rows and columns, which have a length (number of elements) which a commonly known as dimensions

Comment: @nbk I'm looking how  to achieve in multiple  comma  separated  values  into table

Comment: Search for solit function in mysql and you will find multiple solutions as mysql has no build in function for it, i think i made it clear in the first comment aleady

Comment: @nbk I have tried  but with out  any luck. Can you please throw some code suggestions for my reference

Comment: this for examle works and is easy to adept https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755170/5193536

Comment: this  is  not  working  for me