# TSQL for Extracting all the text/string embedded between repeating "@" symbol in a large paragraph in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large text file that will be loaded into a temp table. The file will have sample text like below,

We the People of the United States@  in Order to form a more perfect Union@ establish Justice@ insure domestic Tranquility@ provide for the common defense@ promote the general Welfare@ and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity@ do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America@

I want to extract the text that appears before each "@" symbol and insert each extracted line into separate records in a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    SerialNumber VARCHAR(10),
    Text         VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

After extracting the string the text should be inserted into the temp table.

[image]

So far, this is the code I can think of, Need help to extract the remaining text and insert it into the temp table.

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(max)

SET @test = 'We the People of the United States@  in Order to form a more perfect Union@ establish 
             Justice@ insure domestic Tranquility@ provide for the common defense@ promote the general 
             Welfare@ and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity@ do ordain and 
              establish this Constitution for the United States of America@'

SELECT 
    '1' AS SerialNumber, 
    LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX('@', @test) - 2) AS Text;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a simple _split_ function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848348/1690217 is a good option for this but this dup has a lot more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647/1690217

Comment: This answer has a lot of good advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19935646/1690217 basically split on @ and you're good to go, if you are using SQL Sever 2016 then its built in, for everything else have a look at XML versions

Comment: @Charlieface STRING_SPLIT() not available in 2012?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make the first column an integer and not a string.  Presumably, the purpose is to capture the ordering of the results.

Second, this is a little tricky.  If you trust that `string_split()` returns substrings in order -- which it does in practice but is not documented to always do -- then you can use:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int) as SerialNumber, s.value as text
INTO test1
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@test, '@') s;
```

The problem is that this includes a final row that is empty -- because of the final `@`.  We need to get rid of that.  If no other rows are empty, then the simplest method is to add:

```
WHERE s.value <> ''
```

That works in this case, but a general solution is more complicated.

If you don't want to trust the built-in ordering, then you can add an `order by`:

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX('@' + s.value + '@', '@' + @test + '@')
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate lines in the results.  Once again, that is true for this problem, but not in general.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eab41635219f226ec60da3950dc47fff) is a db<>fiddle.